# Chromium: Corporate HTTPS-Proxy and HPKP

Tags: security, proxy, ssl, certificate, chromium

Chromium version 58.0.3000.4 (64-bit) still works fine, but since 58.0.3029.6 (64-bit) I get `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` for every HTTPS connection.

Clicking "Advanced" shows the following explanation (emphasis not mine):

> This server could not prove that it is **gmx.de**; its security
>   certificate is from **gmx.de**. This may be caused by a misconfiguration
>   or an attacker intercepting your connection. Learn more.

We have a corporate proxy (Astaro) that MITMs https, thus giving me its own certificate (which is trusted in the cert store).

IE in multiple versions works flawlessly and, as mentioned above, the minor release before does, too.

What may be the reason for this error in chromium? Could this be related to HPKP?

Comment: May be this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308330#c40